# NavigationCacheMode. the page is cached for a split second, then renewed

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-8

When setting NavigationCacheMode="Required" I get a cached page, but only for a very short period (0,5 sec), then the page is renewed.

in my code behind I collect data and populate a grid, but I would assume that when a page is cached the code behind is not executed.

Is there a flag I need to set ? Like if(cached)...

Comment: On what event do you start collecting data/populating your grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnNavigatedTo method is called regardless if your page came from the cache or not. You'll need to detect whether the data is already populated and act accordingly.

A little frustrating I know, but there are valid use cases for needing to run whether its cached or not.